# R cannot be resolved to a variable even after cleaning the project

Tags: android

On running the project, R cannot be resolved to variable error occurs and I've tried Cleaning up the Project and Setting the Build Path.

Comment: Have you triple checked that you don't have any xml errors?

Comment: Are you running on linux?

Comment: The Code does not have the import android.R, I've checked it multiple times and also cleaned the project, still the same error exists and this error came after I deleted the R.java file

Answer (score 2):

> R cannot be resolved to a variable even after cleaning the project

So first check if you don't have

```
import android.R;
```

If yes, remove this line. Eclipse sometimes generated it.

If you did it and still is error maybe you have errors(also in XML layouts etc.) in project and if there is at least one error, **`R`** cannot be generated. So check everything also res folder.

You can also go to gen folder, delete `R.java` and clean project again.

Comment: The Code does not have the import android.R, I've checked it multiple times and also cleaned the project, still the same error exists and this error came after I deleted the R.java file.